# What data structures can one use to implement "Ginsberg's partition search" in a game tree search?

Tags: java, artificial-intelligence, minimax, alpha-beta-pruning

I'm building a game tree search for a card game, similar to bridge.  So I started out with building a double dummy solver for bridge.  I'm trying to further optimize the current game tree search algorithm which is based on alpha-beta pruning tree search, enhanced with MTD-f https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MTD-f 
.  (All my current code is in Java)

I've been reading M.Ginsberg's paper on "partition search".  It can be found in many places in the internet e.g. https://www.aaai.org/Papers/AAAI/1996/AAAI96-034.pdf
According to Ginsberg he was gaining an order of magnitude in performance by this.

After heaving read the paper multiple times, I think I more or less understand it, at least the idea is fairly simple, but working it out isn't.

- I'm not sure fully understanding how the complexity of the intersection in the algorithm is avoided by doing null-window searches, although it isn't hard to see that it converts a complex problem to a binary 0 or 1 problem.
- Ginsberg goes on to note in his bridge example

  > "although the details of the approximation functions and data structures are dependent on the rules of bridge and a discussion of their implementation is outside the scope of this paper"

I totally do not see, what sort of data structures can be used to implement this e.g. the first line of the algorithm:

```
if there is an entry (S,[x,y],z) with p elemOf S return (z,S)
```

Where

- "entry" refers to an entry in some form of "transposition table"
- p is a position (as one typically has it in a game tree)
- S is a set of positions!
- [x,y] is the possible outcome interval, similar to alpha and beta

This

- somehow requires a transposition table where the keys are sets of positions?!
- how does one determine elemOf?
  ...

Similarly for the partioning system, referred to as (P,R,C) in the paper.  How does one go about building the "approximating functions" for these?

I seem unable to find implementations of this idea, data structures to support it ....  Has anyone tried?  Is it really worth all the effort?

P.S.
The only reference to something similar, I found, was the master thesis of S.Kupferschmid on: http://gki.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/theses/diploma_de.html
(fully in German though, and it only defines an equivalence relationship between cards that takes a Skat particularity into account.  For something like bridge this is similar to "rank equivalence" i.e. if you have 6 and 4 of the same suit and the 5 of that suit was played then 6 and 4 are equivalent for the outcome of the game)

Comment: I found another reference to something similar, this time it's called fuzzy transposition table: "... fuzzy transposition table, which clusters strategically similar positions into generalised game states." (http://cit.fer.hr/index.php/CIT/article/view/1516/1220)  but still no clue as how to implement it.